# Принудительный try-catch для пользовательского метода

Tags: c#

Существует ли какой-то механизм в C# для пользовательского метода пользовательского класса, который будет принуждать использовать данный метод во внешнем коде только в блоке try-catch ?

Comment: нет. checked exceptions как в java тут нет. и это хорошо. Ибо вызывающему коду виднее когда и что он должен перехватывать.

Comment: "для пользовательского метода пользовательского класса" - приведите пример.

Comment: @vitidev стоит запостить как ответ

Comment: @Igor public class Division {public decimal Calculate(decimal a, decimal b) {return a / b;}}

Comment: @maratsoft - Что же Вы на ходу условия меняете? Так виртуальный это метод или нет?

Comment: @Igor это не я свой вопрос правил.

Comment: @maratsoft - это я перенес код из Вашего первоначального комментария в вопрос (где его можно отформатировать). В том коде присутствовала виртуальность, позволявшая обернуть метод, переписанный наследником, в `try-catch` на уровне базового класса. Мой ответ имеет смысл в свете того комментария, которого уже нет :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В c# нет аналога java checked exceptions, поэтому метод никак не может потребовать использовать try/catch в месте вызова этого метода.

Вызывающий код сам решает на каком уровне ему использовать try..catch и из вложенного кода нельзя управлять этим.

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class BinaryOperation 
{
  protected abstract decimal DoCalculate(decimal a, decimal b);

  public decimal Calculate(decimal a, decimal b) 
  { 
    try {
      return DoCalculate(a, b);
    } catch(...) {
      ...
    }
    return 0; 
  } 

  public abstract string Name { get; }
}


public class Division : BinaryOperation 
{ 
  protected override decimal DoCalculate(decimal a, decimal b) 
  { 
    return a / b; 
  } 

  public override string Name 
  { 
    get { return "Деление"; } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: А кто минусует, чего тут неправильного то? Вполне корректный способ обернуть потенциально опасные переопределенные в наследниках участки кода.

Comment: @Monk поставил плюс, но неправильное тут то, что это не ответ. Тут вызывающий метод *сам решил* обернуть вызываемый в try..catch (а может этого не делать), а по логике тс вызываемый метод должен *заставить* применять try..catch

Comment: @vitidev проблему небезопасного вызова оно решает.